# Window.prompt() is submitting my formulary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a form and inside it a button that prompts a window like this:

```
<form action="X">
    <!-- Some other fields -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.prompt("SOME TEXT", $var);
    </script>
    <!-- Submit button of the form -->
</form>
```

The window's purpose is to make the user able to copy a text (which is inside the  variable) pressing CTRL+C and then, close the window by hitting ENTER or ESCAPE.

My trouble is that when I close the window, doesn't matter how (clicking on "Accept", "Cancel" or pressing ENTER or ESCAPE), my form is submitted.

I appreciate so much your help,

Best.

EDIT:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <button id="copiar" style="margin-left: 65px;" onclick="copyToClipboard('Copy this')">'Button'</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
      window.prompt("Para copiar las etiqetas pulsa Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).keyup(function(e) {                
        if(e.which == 13) {                
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        }
      });
    });

  </script>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet that reproduces this? Most likely you have some other code (executed after the `.prompt`) that submits your form

Comment: Have you tried adding `event.preventDefault();` to your javascript?

Comment: @NewToJS — Since there isn't an `event`, that won't do much good.

Comment: Your posted code isn't relevant to your issue

Comment: @Quentin as pointed out, it's most likely Saso222 has some other code submitting the form. Meaning this isn't all of the relevant source code. using preventDefault() will stop the default behaviour of the form.

Comment: Here are so many smart people. Quentin, provide an idea :)

Comment: @NewToJS But OP seems like he wants user to be able to submit the form, later

Comment: It's very probably that OP is searching for a solution like my answer. However, you are very smart people, I delete my answer and you have free way to answer all of you. Good luck.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude `It's very probably that OP is searching for a solution like my answer.` Ya exactly my first though (that's why i didn't downvoted your answer) but that's just a guess

Comment: @A.Wolff "doesn't matter how (clicking on "Accept", "Cancel" or pressing ENTER or ESCAPE), my form is submitted" My comment is purely suggesting how to stop the form submitting. Since the OP hasn't show any attempt to control the clients actions of the prompt I won't do all the work for them, hence commenting and making suggestions.

Comment: Why didn't you said you were clicking the button (wich default type is submit)???

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Finally your posted deleted answer was very relevant

Comment: Wasn't relevant, but I was going by the good way. However, I receive 3 fast downvotes, I remove the answer. Sometimes this website makes me crazy with someone that downvote without thinking before. The downvote it's for another purposes, not to say that's not the real solution.

Comment: @NewToJS And you were right

Comment: @A.Wolff I know. I could tell the OP didn't include all of the relevant source code but for it to submit no matter what something had to be triggering the form. Hence suggesting preventing default action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <button id="copiar" style="margin-left: 65px;" onclick="copyToClipboard('Copy this')">'Button'</button>
> ```

That is a submit button. It is supposed to submit the form. This has nothing to do with the `prompt`.

Use a plain button. Add `type="button"`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for your help, Quentin.